# Bonsai ficus Ginseng leaves yellowing and falling off

Tags: bonsai, ficus

Suddenly my ficus started yellowing some leaves and every day around 5-10 leaves fall off.
What could the diagnosis be?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There may be many possible reasons for yellowing of leaves. Improper water is one of the most prominent. You might like to look into [this](https://www.bonsaitreegardener.net/care/how-to/turning-yellow), containing a nice guide for bonsai care.

Comment: The same happened with my plant too. I changed my watering cycle and now it seems to be better.

Comment: Seems like over watering, could you share how often are you watering the plant?